# Python dataframes - How to track recent lowest value

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I have a data frame like below in a dataframe called data

```
SN  value
1   895.1
2   900.94
3   920.26
4   918.9
5   927.23
6   919.32
7   923.33
8   896.42
9   898.72
10  881.03
11  879.56
12  882.68
13  879.13
14  901.05
15  905.84
16  932.68
17  940.74
```

I need to keep track of recent lowest value.
I tried

```
# creating new column to track recent low and initializing all values to first value. This is to update it if a new low value is found
# data['new_low'] = data.iat[0,0]

#creating another column to compare last two rows and record whether it is new low or not
data['is_new_low'] = data.value.lt(data.new_low)
#if new low is found, make current value as the new low, otherwise keep the previous value
data['new_low'] = np.where((data['is_new_low']== True),data.value,data.new_low.shift())
```

This code is working for one pass. But when the flips for 2nd time, its not updating. Refer Row with SN 14

**My Code out put**

```
SN  value   new_low is_new_low
1   895.1   NaN     FALSE
2   900.94  895.1   FALSE
3   920.26  895.1   FALSE
4   918.9   895.1   FALSE
5   927.23  895.1   FALSE
6   919.32  895.1   FALSE
7   923.33  895.1   FALSE
8   896.42  895.1   FALSE
9   898.72  895.1   FALSE
10  881.03  881.03  TRUE
11  879.56  879.56  TRUE
12  882.68  882.68  TRUE
13  879.13  879.13  TRUE
14  901.05  895.1   FALSE #Here it should be 879.13. But 895.1 is coming
15  905.84  895.1   FALSE
16  850.2   895.1   TRUE 
17  870.14  895.1   TRUE
```

**Desired output is**

```
SN  value   new_low is_new_low
1   895.1   NaN FALSE
2   900.94  895.1   FALSE
3   920.26  895.1   FALSE
4   918.9   895.1   FALSE
5   927.23  895.1   FALSE
6   919.32  895.1   FALSE
7   923.33  895.1   FALSE
8   896.42  895.1   FALSE
9   898.72  895.1   FALSE
10  881.03  881.03  TRUE
11  879.56  879.56  TRUE
12  882.68  882.68  TRUE
13  879.13  879.13  TRUE
14  901.05  879.13  FALSE
15  905.84  879.13  FALSE
16  850.2   850.2   TRUE
17  870.14  870.14  FALSE
```

**How to achieve this ?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use df.itertuples() to iterate through all your rows and update the new_low value. For every row, check if your value is less than the new_low value in previous row. If yes, update the new low value as the current value else set the new_low value to the new_low value of previous column.

```
for row in data.itertuples():
    if(row.Index):
        if data.at[row.Index,"value"] < data.at[row.Index -1,"new_low"]:
            data.at[row.Index,"new_low"] = data.at[row.Index,"value"]
        else:
            data.at[row.Index,"new_low"] = data.at[row.Index -1,"new_low"]
```

You can also do something like this:

```
df['new_low'] = df['value'].cummin()
```

And if you'd like to use numpy for better performance, you can use:

```
np.minimum.accumulate(df.value)
```